# How to increase width of the text in a CSS button keeping the button width constant?

Tags: css

```
.buttonScheme1 {
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05,       #33bdef), color-stop(1, #019ad2));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#33bdef',endColorstr='#019ad2',GradientType=0);
background-color:#33bdef;
-moz-border-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-radius:0px;
border-radius:3px;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
    padding: 30px 30px; 
text-decoration:none;
    min-width: 50px;
    min-height: 40px;
    max-height: 40px;
    max-width: 50px;
}
```

I want to increase the text width so that the text is adjustable inside the button even if the name of the button is larger. In current situation the width is less so the text is coming to the next line.

Comment: I believe seeing a distinct width and height as week as setting box-sizing: border-box just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to adjust the padding and the width.

Padding will offset the text inside the button. If you decrease the padding to 10px and set the width to 90px (50px + 40px for the padding you lost) that'll give you more room for text.

At some point though - depending on how much text you have - you'll have to increase the button width.

You can also use: `box-sizing: border-box;` to freely adjust the padding without adjusting the width.